# Way to specify default autowireMode in spring kotlin support

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Spring boot version 2, spring framework version 5.

How do I specify default `autowireMode` for beans DSL? I currently use this for each bean:

```
fun beans() = org.springframework.context.support.beans {
    bean<BeanImpl>(autowireMode = BeanDefinitionDsl.Autowire.BY_NAME)
    bean<AnotherBeanImpl>(autowireMode = BeanDefinitionDsl.Autowire.BY_NAME)
    // hundreds more bean
}
```

which is tedious. The bean implementations are from legacy app, so I cannot use `Component`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your own extension method:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> BeanDefinitionDsl.beanByName(name: String? = null,
                                          scope: Scope? = null,
                                          isLazyInit: Boolean? = null,
                                          isPrimary: Boolean? = null
                                          isAutowireCandidate: Boolean? = null) {
  this.bean(name = name, scope = scope, isLazyInit = isLazyInit, isPrimary = isPrimary, isAutowireCandidate = isAutowireCandidate, autowireMode = Autowire.BY_NAME)
}
```

And then use it

```
fun beans() = org.springframework.context.support.beans {
    beanByName<BeanImpl>()
    beanByName<AnotherBeanImpl>()
    // hundreds more bean
}
```